# Редирект nginx с русского доменного имени

Tags: nginx, администрирование, веб-сервер

Доброго времени дня. Настроил редирект с доменного имени с www на доменное имя без www.

```
server {
     listen  80;
     server_name  www.someserver.ru;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://someserver.ru$1 permanent;
}
```

Добавил в файл конфигурации такой же блок, но с русским доменным именем:

```
server {
     listen  80;
     server_name  мой-сервер.рф;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://someserver.ru$1 permanent;
}
```

Редирект с доменного имени www.someserver.ru работает, а с доменного имени мой-сервер.рф переходит на тестовую страницу nginx. Пробовал также в конфиге вместо *мой-сервер.рф* использовать юникодовскую строку, но результат тот же. Как можно исправить проблему? 

С уважением, maxspb.

Comment: А что говорят логи? Наверняка там можно найти, какой server_name увидел nginx при запросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам поможет замена доменного имени на его же в [punycode](https://www.punycoder.com/). Это стандарт преобразования доменных имён из произвольных символов в домены из латинских символов. Например, так:

```
server {
     listen  80;
     server_name  xn----jtbanomrbf6a.xn--p1ai;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://someserver.ru$1 permanent;
}
```

Дело в том, что система доменных имён изначально не поддерживает не-латиницу, поэтому добавили punycode - это костыль со стороны пользовательских приложений, который за кадром преобразует имя в юникоде во что-то на латинице.

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, к сожалению не получается

Comment: Так, я вставлял косячный puny. Конвертировал при помощи сайта и все заработало, спасибо.

Comment: @maxspb89 Пожалуйста. Пометьте тогда, пожалуйста, ответ как верный. Мне кажется, вопрос и ответ могут оказаться полезны другим.